# Complexity of exact inference on graphical models

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference

I'm currently self studying these [notes](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/courses/csc412/lectures/05-exactInference.pdf) and in this slide it says that naively marginalizing over all unobserved variables requires an exponential number of computations. Does anyone know why it is exponential?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $W=(W_1,\ldots,W_n)$, where each $W_i$ is binary.
Then $W$ can take on $2^n$ different values, so the sum $\sum_w P(Y,e,w)$ is over $2^n$ terms.